# What defines the extent to which a business can voluntarily lie to its customers?

Tags: contract-law, false-advertising

Businesses' communication is a constant stream of lies:

- on the phone:

  - our menu options have changed
  - we're experiencing a higher than normal call volume
  - your call is important to us
- when advertising:

  - the best pizza in town
  - scientifically proven
  - lose x pounds in y hours
  - all natural
- when talking to you:

  - I'll get on it right away
  - we'll call you right back
  - we charged you this fee for your convenience
  - we take x very seriously

on the internet it's also endless...

My question is not about the dangerous lies that can have consequences (eat a lemon and you won't get covid), but rather the continuous stream of lies that have been accepted as business as usual.

I can see them used to either:

- steer a customer in a direction and / or state of mind. For example buy this, be patient with us, etc
- or to make interactions smoother and avoid confrontation by pretending to care for example.

So what would be the threshold for a lie to be actionable where you could claim a damage? Does it always have to be material damage? or would a waste of time also be valid for example?

Answer (score 4):

> what would be the threshold for a lie to be actionable where you could claim a damage?

There is no award for "lies" which clearly are inconsequential.

A customer will never make decisions based on whether "*menu options have changed*" or whether the business is honest on the statement "*your call is important to us*". The impact that the duration of these statements have on the customer is negligible at best, since omitting these statements does not improve the company's response time anyway.

The statement "*your call is important to us*" might not even be a lie. Many companies know that it is in their best interest to gather information from their customers on what to improve, lest customers switch to a competitor or file suit.

The lack of objective standards renders statements such as "*best pizza in town*" unascertainable. Accordingly, it would be unreasonable for a customer to rely on criteria that are subjective, undefined, unclear, and/or palpably fictitious.

Only statements like "*scientifically proven*" and "*lose x pounds in y hours*" might be within scope of consumer protection laws (see also *unfair and misleading practices*). The assessment of those scenarios requires more detail, including disclaimers and other "small letters" that are --or ought to be-- disclosed no later than the formation of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of bullshit.

> what would be the threshold for a lie to be actionable where you could claim a damage? Does it always have to be material damage? or would a waste of time also be valid for example?

So long as you can **quantify** your damage in dollars/pounds/goats, you can potentially have a case.

Answer (score 0):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### Deceptive or misleading conduct in trade or commerce illegal

This has been interpreted by the courts as conduct that would deceive or mislead a reasonable consumer. It’s also the case that if you are not in “trade or commerce” )e.g. politics) you can say whatever the f#@k you like.

> - our menu options have changed: is neither deceptive nor misleading if their menu options have changed.
> - we're experiencing a higher than normal call volume: is also ok providing that they don’t say this more than 50% of the time. More than that a d there are legitimate issues to be raised about what a reasonable person thinks “normal” means.
> - your call is important to us: self-evidently true. Especially if you attach the adjective “not-very”.
> - the best pizza in town: advertising “puff” and allowed under the law. A reasonable person does not expect “best X in Y” to be an objectively verifiable claim.
> - scientifically proven: now we’re getting into the weeds - you better have your studies and they better be published in peer-reviewed journals. [Bullshit](https://www.accc.gov.au/publications/advertising-selling/advertising-and-selling-guide/marketing-claims-that-require-extra-care-premium-and-credence-claims/health-claims-and-other-benefits) won’t wash.
> - lose x pounds in y hours: ditto.
> - all natural: no problem there. So long as your product is free on man-made additives.
> - I'll get on it right away: a reasonable person equates “right away” with “soon” not “immediately”.
> - we'll call you right back: ditto.
> - we charged you this fee for your convenience: I have literally never heard this.
> - we take x very seriously: sure, why wouldn’t they?

*You* can’t take action for a breach of this aspect of the Australian Consumer Law but the Australian Competition an Consumer Commission [has](https://www.accc.gov.au/publications/advertising-selling/advertising-and-selling-guide/avoid-misleading-or-deceptive-claims-or-conduct/misleading-or-deceptive-conduct) and does. As do their state and territory counterparts.

Comment: "we charged you this fee for your convenience", Bank of America had the nerves to tell me that they charged me for some service I didn't want, which had a fee, for my own convenience. When they hit the bottom, they start to dig :)

Comment: Misrepresentations must also be material. "our menu options have changed" is not actionable even if it is a bald faced mistruth.

Comment: @ohwilleke not in Australia - misleading and deceptive conduct does not have to be about anything material.

Comment: @DaleM I would be shocked if there wasn't some doctrine that had the effect of weeding out immaterial statements.

Comment: @ohwilleke remember they are only actionable by the ACCC or state equivalents so prosecutorial discretion is available.